# Same php variables, different content. How to differentiate?

Tags: php, opencart

I've got a bit stuck with my Opencart store and php variables. Here is the thing:

Each product has `<?php echo $product['name']; ?>` for name (and similar for thumb, price etc.).
I have pages with multiple products listed. For example I want to add some hover div to each product, which would contain name, thumb, price etc.

But when I add a respective script to my template and `<div id="hidden"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></div>` it gives me a name of the very first product, not for that specific one I toggle.

How would I make it display data for a specific element if a variable is exactly the same? I'll be grateful for any hint!

Comment: i am not sure i understand your question, how do you have multiple `$product['name']` variables? are they items in a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want to add an event hover in each of your products? 
maybe you can try this, example :

```
  <?php 
  while($product = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  { ?>
  <div class="thumb-prod">
    <img src="img/<?php echo $product['image'] ?>" />
    <div class="name-prod">
        <?php echo $product['name'] ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

now ,require the newest jquery and add this script :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.thumb-prod').hover(function(){
           var name = $(this).find('.name-prod');
           name.show();
      }, function(){
           var name = $(this).find('.name-prod');
           name.hide();
      });
   });
</script>
```